# raw h264 data to RTSP

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, python-gstreamer

I will be having raw h264 stream in a pipe and I have to serve it with RTSP.
How to do this in python and gstreamer.

Currently I'm able to play the stream with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ffmpeg", "-i", "-", "-f", "rawvideo", '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', "pipe:1"], stdin=f,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: check this project: https://pypi.org/project/rtsp/

Comment: @BijayRegmi I need to host a rtsp server. pypi.org/project/rtsp is a rtsp client. Sorry for very the late reply